# unable to read librdkafka file showing undefined reference to `rd_kafka_header_get_all'

Tags: go, gcc, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I'm trying to set up my project and try to make a build or try to run but every time it showing this error undefined reference. what I learned until now my code is not able to read librdkafka's files.

I tried to change locations where I installed these tools or libraries, I tried to change versions of them, but didn't succeed to resolve it.

these are the locations where libraries installed.

```
/opt/apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin 
/opt/zookeeper
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go
/home/harishrana/librdkafka
```

and this is the location where my project is situated.

```
/home/harishrana/go/src/autoextraction
```

this is the error coming

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_AlterConfigs_result_resources':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:124: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_AlterConfigs_result_resources'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_is_read_only':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:143: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_is_read_only'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_is_sensitive':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:162: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_is_sensitive'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_is_synonym':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:181: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_is_synonym'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_name':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:199: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_name'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_source':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:218: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_source'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_synonyms':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:237: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_synonyms'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_value':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:255: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigEntry_value'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_configs':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:274: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_configs'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_error':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:305: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_error'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_error_string':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:323: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_error_string'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_name':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:341: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_name'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_new':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:361: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_new'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_set_config':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:382: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_set_config'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_type':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:401: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_type'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigSource_name':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:420: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigSource_name'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_CreatePartitions_result_topics':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:455: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_CreatePartitions_result_topics'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_CreateTopics_result_topics':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:490: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_CreateTopics_result_topics'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_DeleteTopic_new':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:520: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_DeleteTopic_new'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_DeleteTopics_result_topics':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:555: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_DeleteTopics_result_topics'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_DescribeConfigs_result_resources':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:590: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_DescribeConfigs_result_resources'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_NewPartitions_new':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:623: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_NewPartitions_new'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_NewPartitions_set_replica_assignment':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:648: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_NewPartitions_set_replica_assignment'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_NewTopic_new':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:682: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_NewTopic_new'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_NewTopic_set_config':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:703: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_NewTopic_set_config'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_NewTopic_set_replica_assignment':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:728: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_NewTopic_set_replica_assignment'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ResourceType_name':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:747: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ResourceType_name'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_AlterConfigs_result':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:796: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_AlterConfigs_result'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_CreatePartitions_result':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:814: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_CreatePartitions_result'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_CreateTopics_result':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:832: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_CreateTopics_result'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_DeleteTopics_result':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:850: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_DeleteTopics_result'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_DescribeConfigs_result':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:868: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_DescribeConfigs_result'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_error':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:899: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_error'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_error_string':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:917: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_error_string'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_type':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:936: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_type'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_queue_poll':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1008: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_queue_poll'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_topic_result_error':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1027: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_topic_result_error'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_topic_result_error_string':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1045: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_topic_result_error_string'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_topic_result_name':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1063: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_topic_result_name'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_AdminOptions_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:92: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_AdminOptions_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_AlterConfigs':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:108: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_AlterConfigs'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_ConfigResource_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:289: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_ConfigResource_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_CreatePartitions':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:439: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_CreatePartitions'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_CreateTopics':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:474: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_CreateTopics'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_DeleteTopic_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:505: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_DeleteTopic_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_DeleteTopics':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:539: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_DeleteTopics'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_DescribeConfigs':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:574: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_DescribeConfigs'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_NewPartitions_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:605: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_NewPartitions_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_NewTopic_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:663: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_NewTopic_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000019.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:883: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000020.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_AdminOptions_new':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:45: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_AdminOptions_new'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000020.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_AdminOptions_set_operation_timeout':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:68: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_AdminOptions_set_operation_timeout'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000020.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_AdminOptions_set_request_timeout':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:91: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_AdminOptions_set_request_timeout'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000020.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_AdminOptions_set_validate_only':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:114: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_AdminOptions_set_validate_only'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000022.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_conf_set_default_topic_conf':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:93: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_conf_set_default_topic_conf'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_assign':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:65: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_assign'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_assignment':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:85: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_assignment'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_commit_queue':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:108: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_commit_queue'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_committed':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:130: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_committed'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_consumer_close':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:163: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_consumer_close'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_name':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:181: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_name'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_topic_partition_list':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:199: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_topic_partition_list'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_offsets_store':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:219: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_offsets_store'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_pause_partitions':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:239: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_pause_partitions'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_poll_set_consumer':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:258: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_poll_set_consumer'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_queue_get_consumer':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:276: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_queue_get_consumer'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_queue_get_main':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:294: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_queue_get_main'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_resume_partitions':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:314: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_resume_partitions'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_seek':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:338: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_seek'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_subscribe':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:358: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_subscribe'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_subscription':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:378: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_subscription'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_add':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:399: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_add'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_new':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:430: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_new'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_unsubscribe':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:449: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_unsubscribe'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_conf_set_events':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:147: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_conf_set_events'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000023.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:414: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000025.o: In function `chdrs_to_tmphdrs':
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:38: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_header_get_all'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000025.o: In function `_rk_queue_poll':
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:53: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_destroy'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:55: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_queue_poll'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:56: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_type'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:63: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_message_next'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:64: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_message_timestamp'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:67: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_message_headers'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/event.go:68: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_header_cnt'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000025.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_message_array':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:68: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_message_array'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000025.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_message_count':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:86: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_message_count'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000025.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_stats':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:104: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_stats'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000025.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_event_topic_partition':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:122: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_event_topic_partition'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000025.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_topic_partition_destroy':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:137: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_topic_partition_destroy'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000027.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_last_error':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:43: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_last_error'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000031.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_query_watermark_offsets':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:169: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_query_watermark_offsets'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000033.o: In function `_cgo_a32e55418a84_Cfunc_rd_kafka_offsets_for_times':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:65: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_offsets_for_times'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000034.o: In function `tmphdrs_to_chdrs':
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/producer.go:43: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_headers_new'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/producer.go:46: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_header_add'
/tmp/go-link-908398633/000034.o: In function `do_produce':
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/producer.go:98: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_producev'
/home/harishrana/go/src/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka/producer.go:112: undefined reference to `rd_kafka_headers_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0x9ce3): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0x9d06): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0x9d3e): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0x9d9d): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0x9dcc): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xa988): undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xaafc): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xab11): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xab2c): undefined reference to `crc32'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xaba7): undefined reference to `deflateBound'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xac41): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xad53): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xade0): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdkafka_broker.o): In function `rd_kafka_broker_thread_main':
(.text+0xaf1b): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdgz.o): In function `rd_gz_decompress':
(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdgz.o): In function `rd_gz_decompress':
(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `inflateGetHeader'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdgz.o): In function `rd_gz_decompress':
(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdgz.o): In function `rd_gz_decompress':
(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdgz.o): In function `rd_gz_decompress':
(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdgz.o): In function `rd_gz_decompress':
(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.a(rdgz.o): In function `rd_gz_decompress':
(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It seems as if your librdkafka version is outdated. Install v1.1.0 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely an issue with the librdkafka version. Can you download from the source?

Steps to be followed:

```
git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git
cd librdkafka
./configure --prefix /usr
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: How do I set this up using a Dockerfile

Comment: @dapo You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128541/build-golang-application-with-librdkafka-in-a-debian-docker-image