# Build Golang Application with librdkafka in a Debian Docker Image?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, debian, librdkafka

With Alpine, Alpine fully supports recent versions of librdkafka, I can just do `apk add` in my Dockerfile, and the following works:

```
FROM golang:1.13-alpine3.10 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
COPY src ./src/

RUN set -eux; \
  apk add --no-cache gcc git libc-dev librdkafka-dev; \
  go build -o ./ ./...
```

Now, for a particular project, I need to make Debian friendly binaries, that will run on Debian/Ubuntu servers.

The problem is that:

- The official Debian repositories only support really old 0.11.x versions of librdkafka. Even for stretch and buster including backports repos. They don't have more recent versions.
- The official Confluent repositories only support librdkafka on Debian 8 (jessie). They don't support librdkafka at all on Debian 9 (stretch) or 10 (buster) due to a libssl version incompatibility.
- The official golang images only support Debian 9 (stretch) and 10 (buster). They don't support Debian 8 (Jessie).

My options:

- Use a dev branch of the Golang Kafka client that doesn't need librdkafka installed at the system level. This would be amazing if it was stable and recommended.
- Manually install/build librdkafka on Debian 9/10.
- Get a Debian 8 golang image?
- Can I do Debian target builds from Alpine? I suspect no, but it's worth asking.

What is the recommended solution?

Comment: We're working to include librdkafka, and its dependencies, with the Go client, to rid the developer of the dependency burden. You can try it out on the WIP repo https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go-dev, it is as simple as changing your imports to `....-dev`. Example here: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go-example/blob/master/main.go#L23

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution which worked for me. I had to download it from source and it gives the latest version

Sample Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.12.9-alpine AS build-stage

LABEL app="application_name"

ENV PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

# Because of https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14914
# required by go get
RUN apk add --update --no-cache alpine-sdk bash python ca-certificates \
      libressl \
      tar \
      git openssh openssl yajl-dev zlib-dev cyrus-sasl-dev openssl-dev coreutils

WORKDIR /src/application_name

RUN git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git
WORKDIR /src/application_name/librdkafka
RUN /src/application_name/librdkafka/configure --prefix /usr
RUN make
RUN make install

WORKDIR /src/application_name
COPY . .
# build the application
RUN GOOS=linux go build -a -o image-name .
```

Comment: If you are building on Alpine, why not just use this: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=librdkafka&branch=v3.10

Comment: Thanks for the option. I wasn't aware of it

Comment: @rvl007 how do i get the link to the files listed at that link

Comment: @dapo you can use the dockerfile sample mentioned above in the answer section.